# Posting To Server With C#

Tags: c#

I saw an online compiler of 'C' built in php.I am using fiddler 2 tool to look what my web-browser is posting to the server.
The content send to the server looks like:

[image]

Can any body tell ,what i should POST to the server using WEBCLIENT OR WEBREQUEST in C# so that i can generate the above text.
The numbers written above vary every time i POST.
Please help.

Comment: the number-changing is a feature ;) it increases security. now be so kind and tell us to which server you want to post

Comment: Its a linux webserver,which invokes GCC shell.

Answer (score 0):

The number changing is a feature, as Vogel612 said.

Anyway, to post to the server with a WebClient you need to call the `UploadStringAsync` method and write a handler when the `UploadStringCompleted` event is raised. This is a very quick WinForms program I created with a multiline `TextBox` which posts C code to a compiler service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace WebClientPostForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PostToServer();
        }

        public void PostToServer()
        {
            TxtOutput.Text += "Initialising... ";

            // string is formatted like this for readability
            string code = "int main()" +
            "{" +
                "printf(\"Hello World!\");" +
            "}";

            // the code is URL-encoded so that characters are escaped
            string data = string.Format("code={0}&lang=c&submit=Execute", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code));

            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            // I couldn't get this to work unless I set the content type
            client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            client.UploadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => 
                {
                    TxtOutput.Text += string.Format("Request complete. Response: {0}", e.Result);
                };

            TxtOutput.Text += "Posting Data To Server... ";
            client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.compileonline.com/compile.php"), data);
        }
    }
}
```